# Filter on property even if it doesn't exist

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

In angular 1.2 I had an array of objects:

```
[{
  name: 'bob'
},{
  name: 'jack',
  archived: false
},{
  name: 'ted',
  archived: true
}]
```

Then I would ng-repeat over the array of people and try to filter out any object where archived = true

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people | filter: {archived: '!' }">
```

This worked great in angular 1.2

However it stop working when I upgraded to angular 1.3.

I know I can simply write my own filter function, but is there a correct way to filter where a boolean property equals true, where that property might not exist in all objects.

If the property does not exist it should not be filtered.  IE in the example array above only ted should be filtered out.

Comment: Hm.. why not simply use `filter: {archived: true}`?

Comment: Sorry if I was confusing things, I want to filter OUT where archived == true.  Meaning I want all objects in the array to appear if they have archived == false or no archived property at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While this seemed to work in pre 1.3:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people | filter: {archived: '!' }">
```

This works in great in angular 1.3

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people | filter: {archived: '!true' }">
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**: Updated with correct code.

I would create a helper function for this:

```
$scope.notArchived = function(el) {
    return !el.archived;
};
```

HTML:

```
ng-repeat="person in people | filter: notArchived"
```

Comment: Wrong direction, see other comments.

Comment: I see, I would create a helper function for this. But I see you found more concise way.